# iOS encryption export compliance

Tags: ios, encryption, app-store-connect

We are trying to upload an App to the iOS store with some simple encryption uses such as AES-256 and HTTPS. This used to be easy in the past you would just say yes you use encryption and then say you are exempt by some following question. But now it asks for documentation even if you are using standard encryption or you can't upload to the France App Store. Does anyone have any idea what the encryption documentation is supposed to look like for such a simple usage. We don't want to not be able to upload to the France App Store.

[Encryption Details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Fgz5.png)

[France Store Question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k6Wia.png)

[App Encryption Documentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XcWlI.png)

We are looking for an example of what the encryption documentation should look like.

Comment: Does your app implement its own encryption code or does it just make use of the standard crypto libraries in iOS?  If the second, then check the fourth box on the first screen and you should be good

Comment: Shouldn't it be the second box, since it states standard encryption algorithms. We use Https and AES-256 in our code.

Comment: Yes, but did you implement those algorithms or do you make use of them via the frameworks that iOS provides (eg UrlSession for https) and CryptoKit for AES-256?  It is a somewhat confusing question but it says "standard algorithms...instead of ... accessing the encryption with Apple's operating system".  The implied question is that you have implemented the standard algorithms yourself.

Comment: Oh okay, I will try to check the fourth box and see if  whether Apple will reject or accept our application. Thank you.

Comment: It worked, the application passed the review process.

Comment: I think it should be option 2 as it says "in addition to" in that question: "Standard encryption algorithms instead of, or in addition to, using or accessing the encryption within Apple's operating system"

Comment: @Nir Mind that it says the responsibility will be yours/company's for any problems regarding this question of encryption.
I'm facing the same issue, first to really understand what means "Standard encryption algorithms instead of, or in addition to, using or accessing the encryption within Apple's operating system", and then trying to figure out what should be precisely the content of the "Compliance Documentation".

Here's the Apple documentation about it:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/complying_with_encryption_export_regulations